# Windows 8 desktop applications cannot access Internet connection

Tags: wireless-networking, windows-8, internet-explorer-10

I recently ran into some trouble accessing Internet from any desktop app imaginable (IE10, Spotify, Dropbox, etc.), but all of my Metro apps work fine. I've tried all sorts of suggestions, including resetting Internet Explorer, disabling add-ons, but nothing seems to work. Even Safe Mode with Networking had no effect. Windows troubleshooters can find anything wrong, either.

I'm hesitant to "refresh my PC" because I'm running Windows 8 on Boot Camp, and I **do not** want Boot Camp to be unavailable (it's my only means to get back to Mac!)

I can browse the Internet with Metro IE, but with Flash unavailable at times, I can't use this for everything...

How can I fix this without resetting the entire install?

Comment: Can you test with Chrome Desktop vs Metro - does the same thing happen?

Comment: @Karan I tried. The installer downloaded, but since it's a desktop app, it couldn't download Chrome files! (confirms that all desktop apps are **not** connecting to the Internet properly) really strange...I'll still try to get Chrome somehow, though

Answer (score 0):

Uninstall NVIDIA Forceware Network Access Manager. This fixed the issue for all desktop apps. I am happily answering this from desktop IE 10. :)

Comment: Also, maybe contact NVIDIA so they can fix this...

Answer (score 0):

The method below fixed it for me:
Run the following two commands one at time.
Use an elevated command prompt, hit enter after each command "in bold" and then restart your machine.

`netsh winsock` reset catalog (reset winsock entries)

`netsh int ip reset reset.log hit` (reset TCP/IPnetsh stack)

I found this:[Windows 8 Desktop Mode Apps have no access to internet](http://www.eightforums.com/network-sharing/11100-windows-8-desktop-mode-apps-have-no-access-internet.html)

A great solution, hope this helps